# Программа должна разбить введённое число на цифры и заполнить массив, массив динамический

Tags: c++

```
int N;
cin >> N;   

//находим количество цифр в числе.
int count = 1;
while (N /= 10)
    count++;

//выделяем память для массива с перемоной count 
int *p;
p = new int[count];

//заполняем массив
int i = 0;
while (N){
    p[i++] = N % 10;
    N /= 10;
}

//выводим массив
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    cout << p[i] << ' ';

delete[] p;
```

Comment: При выводе массива программа выводит мусор, в чём моя ошибка?

Comment: В качестве упражнения подсчет числа цифр -- это нормально. Практически же, неплохо бы представлять возможные размеры массива и тогда окажется, что память можно выделить (тем же `new`) сразу. / (Для int  достаточно 10 элементов, причем можно использовать `char`).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После того, как код ниже отработает значение `N` станет равно нулю:

```
while (N /= 10)
   count++;
```

По-хорошему `N` вообще не стоит модифицировать в ходе работы программы (это же всё-таки пользовательские данные). Если возникнет необходимость работать с `N`, и модифицировать как-то значение, то лучше будет ввести дополнительную переменную, а `N` вообще сделать `const`, например:

```
int temp;
cin >> temp;
const int N = temp;

//находим количество цифр в числе.
int count = 1;
temp = N; // Переписываем значение N в temp и работаем с temp
while (temp /= 10)
    count++;

//выделяем память для массива с переменной count 
int *p;
p = new int[count];

//заполняем массив
int i = 0;
temp = N;  // Переписываем значение N в temp и работаем с temp    
do{
    p[i++] = temp % 10;
    temp /= 10;
} while(temp); // Outtruder: В исходном коде ошибка: Массив не инициализируется при N == 0

//выводим массив
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    cout << p[i] << ' ';

delete[] p;
```

*PS ваш код выведет цифры числа в обратном порядке*

Также неплохим вариантом будет использование стека, `std::stack`. Этот способ сразу решает проблему вывода цифр в обратном порядке засчёт устройства стека:

```
#include <stack>

// ...

int temp;
cin >> temp;
const int N = temp;    
stack<int> digits;

do 
{    
  digits.push(temp % 10);
  temp /= 10;
} while(temp);

while (!digits.empty())
{
  temp = digits.top();
  digits.pop();
  cout << temp << " ";
}
```

Comment: В исходном коде и во всех примерах ошибка: цикл с предусловием при заполнении массива цифр. Массив не инициализируется при `N == 0`.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо, не обратил внимания

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотите именно использовать динамический массив, выделенный вручную, ровно того размера, чтобы поместились цифры? Если это требование не является критичным, можно написать очень короткий код, используя `std::vector`. Им можно пользоваться, как массивом, и он сам заботится о выделении, расширении и удалении памяти.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//...

int N;    
cin >> N;
vector<int> digits; // цифры

for (int i = N; i != 0; i /= 10)
    digits.push_back(i % 10);

reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end()); // развернуть

for (unsigned int i(0); i != digits.size(); ++i)
    cout << digits[i] << " ";
```

Мы получим вектор, содержащий все цифры. Как и ответ выше, для `N == 0` вектор будет пуст, нужно вручную обработать этот случай.

Время работы всё ещё линейное от длины числа.

Если вы используете стандарт C++11, можно написать ещё меньший код, который точно в результате не будет занимать лишнюю память:

```
int N;    
cin >> N;
vector<int> digits; // цифры

for (int i = N; i != 0; i /= 10)
    digits.push_back(i % 10);
digits.shrink_to_fit(); // уменьшить используемой памяти до необходимой

reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end()); // развернуть

for (int digit: digits)
    cout << digits[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Если говорить о размере выделенной памяти, то наверное надо все же сказать, что `malloc()` (функция, которая реально выделяет динамическую память) будет выдавать память блоками размером не меньше 16 байт (в 32-bit Linux). (плюс сама структура под vector тоже имеет свой размер).

Comment: @avp Вообще да, но как `vector`, так и `new`, работают поверх `malloc()` и мы не сможем на уровне языка С++ как-либо на это влиять.

Comment: Влиять не можем, а представлять, что происходит на "машинном уровне" должны.

Comment: @avp Это абсолютно верно, и я это понимаю, но вопрос про C++ же, я рассматривал память только на уровне языка C++. Не все же на Линуксе сидят.

Comment: Вопрос. Что быстрее для определения длины, делить в цикле на 10, а потом делать это еще раз, или взять десятичный логарифм + 1?

Comment: @BuilderC Если логарифм точно считается и на него можно положиться, то зависит от системы. Вроде бы десятичный логарифм - сложная процессорная операция, а мы быстро на десять делим. Уже мерять надо.

Comment: @Lapshin Dmitry, нет нужды считать логарифм точно, поскольку от него требуется лишь целая часть

Comment: @BuilderC Всё так зависит от реализации...